# Bootstrap modal stopped working randomly

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have two modal pop-ups on my page that were working perfectly the other day. Now they've stopped working, and I have no clue why.

Here's the link HTML:

```
<a href="#requestSample" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#requestSample">Request Samples</a>
```

Here's the modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="requestSample" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <?php gravity_form(4, $display_title=false, $display_description=false, $display_inactive=false, $field_values=null, $ajax=false); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the page I'm working on: http://michaelscollins.com

Comment: That is strange. It works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/6z3b27nw/

Comment: Your menu disappears for mobile, too. Is that a new symptom?

Comment: No, it's just not optimized for mobile – sending paid traffic to it on desktops.

Comment: Yeah I know the code is right... must be a plugin or something, although I've just disabled a bunch of plugins and it's still not working... hard to diagnose

Comment: Usually that would result in console errors.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing any of those

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but the only solution I could get was when I added the links in the following order:

1. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
2. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
3. `<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if I call .modal('show') on a item that is displayed than it stops working after. 
i.e.

```
$('#modal').modal('show');
$('#modal').modal('show');
$('#modal').modal('hide');
// Modal will not go away after this
```